Noise in audio amplifiers when touching the smartphone touchscreen as an audio source
While observing the audio output of my smartphone on the oscilloscope, I noticed a signal being generated when I touch the touchscreen. This signal is around 500Hz and appears in groups of 3 peaks, with intensity proportional to the skin/touchscreen contact area:

The output is from an AUX cable connected only to the probe.
At a lower level, a similar phenomenon occurs when I bring the palm of my hand close to the touch screen at a few millimeters away, somewhat like a theremin. However, I have never heard anything when I connect the smartphone to headphones, the car amplifier, or the guitar amplifier.
On the other hand, if I connect the audio output to the input of my battery-powered opamp RC4580 (no connection to the AC power grid), the undesired signal is perfectly audible with each touch of the screen. But if I touch GND with my finger, the signal disappears completely:

Output from RC4580 with a bit of ripple at 50Hz plus the aforementioned signal.
The circuit is a very simple inverting summing amplifier:

I have tried with a different model of smartphone, and the same problem occurs, but the buzzing has a different tone.
What could be the cause of this issue, and how could I solve it so that it is not amplified by the opamp? Thank you.
Audio recording of the interference
EDIT: The noise also occurs when only connecting the GND cable, without any audio signal input. Furthermore, it also occurs with a purchased TDA2030 module, so it is not an exclusive problem of my circuit, it is likely to occur in many cases. Additionally, I tried using an audio isolator with a 1:1 transformer, but there was no improvement in this case either.

Isn't the audio shorted out by using a mono (TS) jack? Is the opamp supply referenced to same ground as audio?

Yes, I only have stereo jacks. Yes, common GND, the voltage offset is half of the supply voltage set by pin 3.

You didn't show us the circuitry producing the +4.5V. Since the output is referred to 0V, that's definitely a candidate for noise being injected somehow.

A simple voltage divider with two 100k resistors and a 47μF capacitor.
